# How to move another view controller when i tapped any collection view cell (without taping last cell)?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview

How to move another view controller when i tapped any collection view cell (without taping last cell) ? I don't know how to fix this issue, i am a beginner in iOS App Development.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return addCategory.count + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cellID = indexPath.row < addCategory.count ? "CategoryCell" : "ExtraCell"

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)
    setupCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath, type: cellID)

    return cell
}

func setupCell(cell: UICollectionViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath, type: String) {

    switch(type) {
    case "CategoryCell": setupCategoryCell(cell: cell as! CategoryCollectionCell, indexPath: indexPath)
    case "ExtraCell": setupAddButtonCell(cell: cell as! CategoryExtraCell, indexPath: indexPath)
    default: break
    }
}

func setupCategoryCell(cell: CategoryCollectionCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cat = addCategory[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblHeader.text = cat.category_name

    //cell.lblHeader.text = arrHeader[indexPath.row]
    //cell.lblSubHeader.text = arrSubHeader[indexPath.row]
}

func setupAddButtonCell(cell: CategoryExtraCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Extra Button "Add Button" in a cell
}
```

When I click on any cell (without tapping last cell), then it will not move to another view controller, the app crashes and doesn't show any error.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.collCategory.allowsMultipleSelection = false

    if indexPath.row < addCategory.count {

        print("Main Cell")

        for i in 0..<addCategory.count {

            if indexPath.row == i {
                let categoryTaskVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CategoryTaskVC") as! CategoryTaskVC
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(categoryTaskVC, animated: true)

                //let cat = addCategory[i]
                //categoryTaskVC.lblHeader.text = cat.category_name
                print("OK")
            } else {
                print("error")
            }
        }

    } else {
        print("Add New Cell")

        self.blurEffects()
        view.addSubview(blurEffectView)

        //Alert View Controller when Adding Categories...
        let inputBox = BMInputBox.boxWithStyle(.plainTextInput)
        inputBox.blurEffectStyle = .extraLight

        inputBox.title = NSLocalizedString("Add Category", comment: "")
        inputBox.message = NSLocalizedString("Please enter unique category name.", comment: "")

        inputBox.customiseInputElement = {(element: UITextField) in
            element.placeholder = "Enter a category"
            return element
        }

        inputBox.submitButtonText = NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "")

        inputBox.onSubmit = {(value: String...) in

            //Store value in text field in "text" object.
            for text in value {

                let strCategory = text
                print("STR CATE : \(strCategory)")

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                    //Store category in CoreData
                    categoryCoreData.saveData(tfCat: strCategory)

                    //Fetch Category Data
                    categoryCoreData.fetchData()
                    self.collCategory.reloadData()
                })
            }

            self.blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        inputBox.cancelButtonText = NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "")

        inputBox.onCancel = {
            //Remove blur effects from Superview
            self.blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        inputBox.show()
    }
}
```

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSrFE.png)

[App Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV1SV.png)

[Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1Pgg.png)

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint for all exceptions. Here's how you do it. http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions

Comment: What is the purpose of the `for` loop in `didSelect`?

Comment: transfer data to next screen @Paulw11

Comment: Still facing issue ?

Comment: I understand you are pushing a new view controller,   But the `for` loop seems entirely unnecessary. Why bother trying to find `i == indexPath.row` when you can just use `indexPath,row` directly.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and stepped through your code to see what is happening. I don't see any print statements in your console and there are several conditional statements that could result in your code skipping over sections.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if` branch to this:

```
if indexPath.row < addCategory.count - 1 {

    print("Main Cell")

    let categoryTaskVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CategoryTaskVC") as! CategoryTaskVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(categoryTaskVC, animated: true)
    let cat = addCategory[indexPath.row]
    categoryTaskVC.lblHeader.text = cat.category_name
}
```

Comment: @RahulChopra what is the crash message?

Comment: Nothing will happen, the app is going to hang state and nothing will shown in Console.

Comment: @RahulChopra I'll wait for a screenshot

Comment: Check images in my question

Comment: @RahulChopra that's not the whole xcode.. also try to remove the whole `else` block to make sure it's not messing up the issue here

Comment: else block is used for "adding" cells (check in app screen image).

Comment: @RahulChopra I know. If you don't want my help, just say so.

Comment: @RahulChopra 1. in the screenshot it is clearly obvious you have NOT used my suggestion but you still have your old `if` branch.. 2. the app did not crash, so there is some other problem.. probably frozen or something similar